# How to keep a reference to a single, persisted Realm object

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, persistence, realm

I understand the general concept of how auto-updating results and realm notifications can be used to update my UI. I am trying to wrap my head around the best approach for doing the same for cases where my view controller only every has a single realm object (An example might be a chat controller that has a RLMResults or RLMArray of messages, but only a single "conversation" object).

I have been able to come up with the two approaches below, but neither seems right. What would be the correct way to implement this?

## Approach A:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger objectPrimaryKey;
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyRealmObject *realmObject;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.objectPrimaryKey = 123;
  self.realmObject = [MyDataManager 
                            realmObjectWithID:self.objectPrimaryKey];

  // Set realm notification block
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  self.notification = [[MyDataManager realm] 
                        addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *note, 
                                               RLMRealm *realm) {
    [weakSelf reloadData];
  }];
  [self reloadData];
}

- (void)reloadData {
  if(self.realmObject.isInvalidated) {
    self.realmObject = [MyDataManager 
                            realmObjectWithID:self.objectPrimaryKey];
  }
  // Populate the UI with self.realmObject
}

@end
```

## Approach B:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger objectPrimaryKey;
@property(nonatomic, retain) RLMResults *realmObjectResults;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) MyRealmObject *realmObject;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.objectPrimaryKey = 123;
  self.realmObjectResults = [MyDataManager
                             realmObjectResultsWithID:self.objectPrimaryKey];

  // Set realm notification block
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  self.notification = [[MyDataManager realm]
                       addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *note, 
                                              RLMRealm *realm) {
    [weakSelf reloadData];
  }];
  [self reloadData];
}

- (void)reloadData {
  // Populate the UI with self.realmObject.
  // Don't think we need to check isInvalid here?
}

- (MyRealmObject *)realmObject {
  return self.realmObjectResults.firstObject;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach "A" is correct, although the only time your object would be invalidated is if you've deleted it, at which point re-obtaining it via `realmObjectWithID:` won't make a difference (assuming this is some wrapper around [`+[RLMObject objectForPrimaryKey:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(cm)objectForPrimaryKey:))

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger objectPrimaryKey;
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyRealmObject *realmObject;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.objectPrimaryKey = 123;
  self.realmObject = [MyDataManager 
                            realmObjectWithID:self.objectPrimaryKey];

  // Set realm notification block
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  self.notification = [[MyDataManager realm] 
                        addNotificationBlock:^(NSString *note, 
                                               RLMRealm *realm) {
    [weakSelf updateUI];
  }];
  [self updateUI];
}

- (void)updateUI {
  // Populate the UI with self.realmObject
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You said the only time the object should be invalidated is if its deleted. Wouldn't it also be invalidated if my API wrapper re-fetches the object from the server and then does a `createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:`?

Comment: No, that would just update the object. Updating an object shouldn't delete it.